# firebase login and signup in the frontend security

Tags: javascript, firebase, security, firebase-authentication

I am building a web app using the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_password)` and `signInWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_password)` on the front-end JS.

In the corresponding HTML file, I wrote some inputs for users to enter their emails and passwords

```
  <input id="login_email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
<input id="login_password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
```

In the related JS file, I am logging in or creating an account with the following code:

```
var user_email = document.querySelector("#login_email").value;
var user_password = document.querySelector("#login_password").value;
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_password)
```

or

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_password )
```

Are there any security issues related with that? Do I need to hash the passwords? Do I need to protect against CSRF? I heard that the Firebase's `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_password)` and `signInWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_password)` provide its own hashing or CSRF token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the APIs with the exact password the user wants to use.  There is nothing else required.  Firebase handles all of the cryptography automatically.

Comment: In that case, simply an <input> with document.getElementbyID to grab the password would suffice? No need to protect against CSRF?

Comment: That's all you need to do.

Comment: Gotcha, do I have to sanitize the input?

Comment: What would have to sanitize? Just pass the email address and password requested by the user.